# How can I match the second occurrence of a string without using capture groups

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression that ONLY matches the second occurrence of a given string within a longer string.

Possible examples

```
NSTR; TEST; NSTR
GKOH; NSTR; NSTR; JLAH
GKOH; JLAH; NSTR; CZE; NSTR; FKILL
```

Should match the second NSTR in each case

I can write an expression that only puts the second occurrence into a capture group:

```
.*NSTR.*?(NSTR)
```

However, that's no use to me as I'm writing it to fit in a function, the code of which I have no control over.

It's for use within a function in MusicBee which uses VB.Net

Comment: It's hard to say without you making mention of the regex engine/programming language you're using since regex isn't a one-size-fits-all. But in many regex engines, you can use something like `(\b\w+\b).*(\1)` - second capture group contains it. In [tag:.net] you can use `(?<=(\b\w+\b).*)(\1)`

Comment: [`^.*?NSTR.*?\KNSTR`](https://regex101.com/r/HhvVM3/1)?

Comment: @ctwheels - as I explained above - I can't use capture groups - the function over which I have no control operates against any matches.

Comment: @Wiktor - that produces an error when I try it - "\K" ??

Comment: Ah, so it is .NET, use `(?s)(?<=^(?:(?!NSTR).)*NSTR(?:(?!NSTR).)*)NSTR`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f!NSTR%29.%29*NSTR%28%3f%3a%28%3f!NSTR%29.%29*%29NSTR&i=NSTR%3b+TEST%3b+NSTR)

Comment: @user194276 does `(?<=(\b\w+\b).*)(\1)` without `g` (global) modifier work for you?

Comment: Ah thank you WIktor - that works a treat! I'm going to have to spend a little time puzzling over HOW it works! Many thanks!

Comment: @ctwheels - as I said, I can't use capture groups - the regex is being inserted into a function that will simply act on matches, i.e. I need a true/false response from the regex.

Comment: @user194276 sorry, does `(?<=(\b\w+\b).*)\1` work? It's only using capture groups for backreferences, not actual capture of data.

Comment: @ctwheels - apologies - I hadn't recognised the potential versatility of this expression - it works in RegexBuddy set to .Net, but not unfortunately when inserted into the function within MusicBee - I'm not sure why this is - will play around a bit to see if there's a workaround.

Comment: @ctwheels - OK - my error - the regex works perfectly. If you want to provide it as an answer I'll mark it as such. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following in [.net](/questions/tagged/.net):

```
(?<=(\b\w+\b).*)\1
```

This works as follows:

- `(?<=(\b\w+\b).*)` lookbehind asserting what precedes matches

  - `(\b\w+\b)` capture a word into capture group 1:

    - `\b` word boundary
    - `\w+` match one or more word characters (defined as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) - you can obviously limit this further if you need to, then you'll also need to create your own boundaries to replace `\b` (such as `(?<![a-z])[a-z]+(?![a-z])` for any lowercase letter)
    - `\b` word boundary
  - `.*` matches any character any number of times
- `\1` matches the same text as most recently captured by capture group 1

How this works? Most languages have a regex function or modifier to match all instances (`g` or global matches), and another to match the first. The regex above will scan the string to find the first location where `\b\w+\b` can be found anywhere left of that location and where that result is found again to the immediate right of that location (then we match the word). So `a a a a` will only match the second `a`.

I'm not familiar with MusicBee or whether you're using `$IsMatch`, `$Replace`, or `$RxReplace`, but it seems you can likely use `$First` to grab the first result if either of those functions return multiple values (as in my example of `a a a a`).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer and the explanation also. 
I had written an enormously long statement incorporating around 30 If's, and's and or's to cover every single reference I use. This expression not only replaced that monster, it also covers every new reference I create automatically.
I only need it to flag tracks with multiple identical refs, so I'm using it with $IsMatch and periodically searching for all tracks where that expression returns true at which point I can manually edit them.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, maybe,

```
(((?!NSTR).)*NSTR((?!NSTR).)*)NSTR
```

or,

```
(((?!\bNSTR\b).)*\bNSTR\b((?!\bNSTR\b).)*)\bNSTR\b
```

might be OK to look into.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7dE4R5/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/7dE4R5/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for introducing me to jex.im - what a useful tool. I'd vote your answer up but unfortunately I don't have privilege too yet and I'm afraid ctwheels' answer provides a much neater solution, but thank you anyway!